# Extraction of rows with even numbers of a dataset

Tags: dataset, homework

```
testdataset = 
  Dataset[{ 
    <|"a" -> 3, "b_i" -> "y", "c" -> {3, 8, 9}, "d" -> "three", "student" -> "C"|>, 
    <|"a" -> 8, "b_i" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}, "d" -> "twenty-six", "student" -> "L"|>, 
    <|"a" -> 9, "b_i" -> "x", "c" -> {1}, "d" -> "sixty-nine", "student" -> "Q"|>}
  ]
```

How can I extract all rows which contain an even number in "a", "c", "d" by (a) `Select` and (b) `DeleteCases`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: nice question... (I am currently trying to find books on data science and mathematica)... could you tell me what text book this is from?

Comment: Actually, I'm not using a book. This is from a class I'm currently taking.

Answer (score 3):

## (a)

I found something similar [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0rs3seh0m-yyy007).

Use `EvenQ` inside `Select` to do it with the `Select` function:

```
testdataset[Select[EvenQ[#a] &]]
```

Comment: For column `"d"`: `testdataset[Select[EvenQ[Interpreter["SemanticNumber"][#d]] &]]`

Comment: `DeleteCases[testdataset, KeyValuePattern["a" -> _?OddQ]]`